# What is the best site for asking questions regarding Org-Mode Latex export?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question about how to get my PDF output, via Latex, to look the way that I want, where should I ask it?

I see a range of Org-Mode related questions on StackOverflow.
I think that an argument could be made that it's SuperUser (how to effectively use a given program, in this case Emacs).
It could even fit in the TeX Stack Exchange, but I'm not sure if that is the right community for org-mode questions.

I'd think that Org-Mode questions related to using source blocks and org-babel, literate programming etc. are StackOverflow types of questions, but it seems ambiguous to me whether questions that only relate to customizing the exported document are on topic there.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: If you think your question is about org-mode or org-babel, try https://emacs.stackexchange.com. If you think it's more about LaTeX, use https://tex.stackexchange.com.